# Edit a form with Laravel Framework

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm new to laravel and trying to learn using it. I created a little project for threads. Nothing special. The thing is, the function to edit something doesn't work and I cant see why. Maybe someone of you see the mistake?

thats my Routes:

```
Route::get('/index', 'Test\\TestController@index');
Route::get('/add', 'Test\\TestController@add');
Route::post('/test', 'Test\\TestController@store');
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'Test\\TestController@show');
Route::get('/show/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'edit', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@edit']);
Route::put('/show/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'editing', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@update']);
```

thats the important parts of the edit method:

```
 public function edit($id) {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        return view('test.edit', [
            'thread' => $thread
        ]);
    }

    public function update($id, StoreRequest $request) {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $thread->fill($request->all());
        $thread->save();
        return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@show', [$thread->id]));
    }
}
```

show.blade

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                {{ $thread->thread }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-group"><br>
                <ul>
                    {{$thread->content }}<br><br>
                    {{$thread->created_at->format('d.m.Y H:i:s')}}
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
           <a href="{{ URL::route('edit') }}"><div class="btn btn-primary">Thread bearbeiten</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

edit blade ( formular where the text I want to add is in the textbox and the save button )

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    {!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('PUT')->action(action("Test\\TestController@update", [$thread->id])) !!}
    {!! Former::populate($thread) !!}
    {!! Former::text('thread')->label('Thread') !!}
    {!! Former::text("content")->label("Content") !!}
    {!! Former::large_primary_submit('Save!') !!}
    {!! Former::close() !!}
@stop
```

model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Thread;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model {
    public $table = 'thread';
    public $fillable = [
        'thread',
        'content',
    ];
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE :

No query results for model [App\Models\Thread\Thread].

Comment: Change this `$thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);` to `$thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);`